# Docker connect app to mysql host

Tags: mysql, docker, ubuntu-16.04

I have an Ubuntu 16.04 installation in a vm and I'm trying to run an app inside a docker container and connect it to a MySQL database on the host

I have something like this.. on the host I have the MySQL:

[image]

And when I try to connect my app to the MySQL I got this:

> java.sql.exception: cannot create poolableConnectionFactory ( Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times

I execute my app using a docker-compose:

```
version: '2'
services:
  exo:
    image: exoplatform/exo-community:5.0
    environment:
      EXO_DB_TYPE: mysql
      EXO_DB_NAME: user
      EXO_DB_USER: root
      EXO_DB_PASSWORD: "my-pass"
      EXO_DB_HOST: "127.0.0.1"
      EXO_ADDONS_LIST: exo-jdbc-driver-mysql
    expose:
      - "8080"
      - "3306"
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - exo_data:/srv/exo
      - exo_logs:/var/log/exo
volumes:
  exo_data:
    external:
      name: exo_data
  exo_logs:
    external:
      name: exo_logs
networks:
  default:
      driver: bridge
```

As you can see I try to connect to the MySQL default port... And I just saw that 3306 port is listening on the host.

I also tried to add the following line ( saw on another post)

In my.cnf I have the bind-address 0.0.0.0.

And MySQL is running:

```
root@xxx/# mysqladmin -u root -p status

Uptime: 4784  Threads: 4  Questions: 17  Slow queries: 0  Opens: 114  Flush tables: 1  Open tables: 33  Queries per second avg: 0.003
```

I'm using docker on bridge so I guess I just need to add the port on docker composer in order to connect docker and host. But nothing seems to works. Can someone point me to right direction?

Comment: I think you need specify IP address and give privileges for your DB GRANT ALL ON fooDatabase.* TO fooUser@’1.2.3.4’ IDENTIFIED BY ‘my_password’;

Comment: mysql isn't running in the container right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to connect to the host from the container using `localhost`. This won't work as the container has its own ip and localhost will hit the container and not the host.

Connecting from container to host is a very frequent question on stackoverflow and you can find many answers in [From inside of a Docker container, how do I connect to the localhost of the machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach)

The easiest way (though not recommended) is to use `network_mode: host` inside docker-compose file. In this case, the container will share the networking with the host and localhost will hit the host machine as well.

Comment: i just add the network_mode line to the composer file and everything starts working. This is just for tests, in a production environment we will use bridge perphaps. So thanks, you solved my problem!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need specify IP address:

```
mysql -u root -p -h 44.55.66.77
```

and give privileges for your:

```
DB GRANT ALL ON yourDatabase.* TO root@’1.2.3.4’ IDENTIFIED BY ‘my-pass’;
```

to get IP address inside container you can run this:

```
awk 'END{print $1}' /etc/hosts
```

Comment: I used just the command to grant permissions.. i forgot it to mention on the post, sorry.